# How much white chocolate should I use in a white chocolate cake?

Tags: cake

I am trying to develop a white chocolate cake formula. The recipes that we tried were dry or did not have the right flavor or consistency. I found no guide line as to how much white chocolate to use. Can any one help?  I am concerned that the white chocolate contains sugar, fat and emulsifiers. What I do not know is what percentage should white chocolate be in this recipe that I created?

Here is what I have so far: I have not tried this recipe yet. All I did was the math!

15 oz. cake flour,
2 oz oil,
4 oz butter,
15 oz. sugar,
7 oz. of eggs,
4 oz. milk (hot to dissolve white chocolate),
1 tablespoon + 1 teaspoon baking powder,
1 teaspoon salt,
1 tablespoon vanilla extract,
4 oz. white chocolate (real chocolate containing cocoa butter),

I plan to use creaming method, pre sifting dry ingredients and adding the white chocolate and hot milk just before adding eggs, and bake at 350F.

Is that a good amount of white chocolate?

Comment: Can you give examples of (links to) the recipes you tried, and explain what you didn't like about each specific one? Knowing a recipe and what's wrong with it makes it possible for people to recommend solutions, while telling us a recipe you haven't even tried doesn't really provide a starting point.

Comment: I've edited for clarity without changing the meaning, and I suppose it's not actually a recipe request in current form (which would be off-topic) but it'd still be way way easier for people to answer if you provided examples like I mentioned, or alternatively let us know how the proposed recipe came out.

Comment: Where did the other ingredients / ratios come from? A tried and tested recipe? Experience? Random values? Have you made anything similar to this and how did it turn out? Welcome to the site, btw.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your recipe, there's not enough butter or eggs for the amount of flour and sugar. I'm saying this because I'm assuming the the oz measurements are weights. You could also increase the amount of white chocolate to 6 oz.

Since white chocolate doesn't have much of a presence in a cake - the primary flavour is vanilla - you may want to make a good white or yellow cake and save the white chocolate for a spectacular icing.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a bit more white chocolate like 1 or 2 more ounces

Comment: Generally, it's helpful to give at least a brief explanation as part of an answer.  Why do you think it needs more white chocolate?  Is there some sort of guideline you're basing this on?  Not only will it help the person asking the question to understand your answer, but a more general guideline or explanation could help other people who don't have this exact recipe but have a similar problem.